# How can I get Microsoft Outlook's OAuth API to work with Angularjs and ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, outlook, oauth-2.0

I've been following a Microsoft Outlook Dev Center tutorial ([https://dev.outlook.com/RestGettingStarted/Tutorial/node][1]) to give my users the ability to import their Outlook contacts into my app. So far I have followed the tutorial up to step 4 where I am able to obtain the `authHelper.getAuthUrl()` authorization URL. The url is formatted like this:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize? redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fauthorize&scope=openid+https%3A%2F%2Foutlook.office.com%2Fmail.read&response_type=code&client_id=<SOME GUID>
```

The problem is that when I click on the link I am redirected to my homepage instead of seeing the Outlook authentication window. I suspect this is because I'm using angularjs with ui-router and the `microsoftonline.com` route isn't explicitly set in my app so it logs me out. Any ideas on how to fix this?